# jQuery select by mask

Tags: jquery

I have mutiple inputs on form contained name like `objectName[unique_guid].propertyName`

Only `unique_guid` is different on my inputs.

```
<input id="a_a" name="ObjectName[b15865be-629c-43b6-b1a6-e614d3ffeb67].Color" type="hidden" value="1">
<input id="b_b" name="ObjectName[8867e8e4-429f-4180-89e3-62bf505fcf5d].Level" type="hidden" value="2">
```

How cay I select all that imputs with jquery?

Comment: can you pls add as HTML?

Comment: `$('[name^="objectName"]')` [Attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various attribute based selectors available.

Use [Attribute starts with selector ^=](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('input[name^="ObjectName"]')
```

or in your case `$=` - Attribute ends with.

```
$('input[name$=".Color"]')
```

Combined Selector :

```
$('input[name^="ObjectName"][name$=".Color"]') //If your PropertyName is static.
```